# How to have multiple versions of the same application downloaded on a physical device?

Tags: android, flutter

I am currently using my own application for daily use. However, a problem occurs when trying to develop it: the app is overwritten with my development version.

I want:

1 version as daily driver

1 current play-store version

1 version for development

What can I do to seamlessly use multiple versions on the same device?

Comment: Use different `applicationId` values. For example, you could add `.debug` as a suffix on `debug` builds for your "version for development".

Comment: you can maintain the product flavour for it

Answer (score 0):

use different [varient build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) for different versions of your application.
for example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    }
    productFlavors {
        daily {
            applicationIdSuffix ".daily"
        }
        play {
            applicationIdSuffix ".play"
        }
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }
}
```